# Google Apps Script to Create a Copy of, Rename, and then Reset a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've designed a spreadsheet for tracking status of systems in an enterprise.
It gets updated every 12 hours and then manually renamed based on the date and report number, then it gets archived.

I have created a script that allows the user to create a copy of the current spreadsheet by pressing on a drawing

```
function copyDocs() {
  for(i=0; i<1; i++){
  var drive=DriveApp.getFileById('190X72ZGwHtKaUa5MQerlW2k1ops-zYTnr1UXwuweJxGY');
  drive.makeCopy();
  }
}
```

I have created a script which allows users to reset all the data fields to empty by pressing on an drawing.

```
  function reset() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('STATUS');
    s.getRange("a2:b4").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c3:d4").clearContent();
    s.getRange("e2:f4").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b5").clearContent();
    s.getRange("e5:f5").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c6:d6").clearContent();
    s.getRange("f6").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c7:f10").clearContent();
    s.getRange("a12:f18").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b20:f25").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b27:f31").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b33:f37").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b39:f39").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b41:f46").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b48:f52").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b54:f58").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b60:f60").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b62:f79").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b81:f81").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d83:f91").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d94:f96").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d98:f105").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d107:f109").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c112:f123").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b113:f113").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b115:f115").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b117:f117").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b119:f119").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b121:f121").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b123:f123").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d124:f124").clearContent();
}
```

What I would like to do is to have one "button" for the user that they press and it runs four scripts in succession. I have tried to think through the best way to make this happen and here is what I need help with.

1. Rename the Spreadsheet they are currently working on to the data in merged cells (A2:B4) it will be a number like "17-087"
2. Make a copy of the whole spreadsheet that will automatically save in the same folder
3. Clear data from the specific cells in the "reset" script above
4. Rename the current spreadsheet from the data in cell 'J2'

In theory the user will press a button, it will rename the spreadsheet (not the sheet, but the whole file) to the data in the merged cell ie. "status 17-087", then it will make a copy of the whole Spreadsheet (file), then clear all the designated cells, then rename the spreadsheet back to the data in 'J2' which is "STATUS TEMPLATE".

Can anyone help me work through this multi-step script? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just create a wrapper function `function backupProcess() {rename(); copyDocs(); reset(); rename2();}` and assign it to the image. Or is it the name part you are having problems with?

Comment: With a few quick tweaks that worked perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Could try something like this:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
function onOpen() {
 
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
  var items = [
    {name: 'Backup', functionName: 'backup'},
  ];
    ss.addMenu('Backup', items);
    }
       
    function backup() {
    rename(); 
    copyDocs(); 
    reset(); 
    rename2();
    }
    
     function rename(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var first = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    // renames the google sheet to the data that is in 2nd Row, 3rd Column
    ss.rename(first.getRange(2, 3).getValue());
    }
    
    function copyDocs() {
    for(i=0; i<1; i++){
    var drive=DriveApp.getFileById('190X72ZGwHtKaUa5MQerlW2k1ops-zYTnr1UXwuweJxGY');
    drive.makeCopy();
    }
    }
    
        function reset() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('STATUS');
    s.getRange("a2:b4").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c3:d4").clearContent();
    s.getRange("e2:f4").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b5").clearContent();
    s.getRange("e5:f5").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c6:d6").clearContent();
    s.getRange("f6").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c7:f10").clearContent();
    s.getRange("a12:f18").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b20:f25").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b27:f31").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b33:f37").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b39:f39").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b41:f46").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b48:f52").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b54:f58").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b60:f60").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b62:f79").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b81:f81").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d83:f91").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d94:f96").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d98:f105").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d107:f109").clearContent();
    s.getRange("c112:f123").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b113:f113").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b115:f115").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b117:f117").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b119:f119").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b121:f121").clearContent();
    s.getRange("b123:f123").clearContent();
    s.getRange("d124:f124").clearContent();
    }
    
         function rename2(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var first = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    // renames the google sheet to the data that is in J2
    ss.rename(first.getRange(2, 10).getValue());
    }
```